# Is there a way to extend a Spring Service in order to manage an inherited entity without duplicating code?

Tags: java, spring

I'm playing with a Spring application with 2 controllers and 2 services that manages related entities and I would like to avoid duplicating code. I've got for example a `Person` class with his `PersonRepository`

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;
    String surname;
}
```

And his child `User` with his `UserRepository`

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User extends Person {
    String login;
    String password;
}
```

I've a simple Person service whith business logic:

```
@Service
public class PersonService {
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repo;

    public Iterable<Person> getAll() {
        // Busines Logic
        return repo.findAll();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to create a UserService extending or proxying PersonService and implementing some kind of repository "hiding"? Something like this:

```
@Service
public class UserService extends PersonService {    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository repo;
}
```

that obviously gives this error:
*Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterable<Person> to Iterable<User>* with a controller like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @GetMapping
    public void items() {
        Iterable<User> persons = service.getAll();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following structure:

Common service and repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface PersonRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

}
```

```
public class PersonService<T extends Person> {

    protected PersonRepository<T> repository;

    public <R extends PersonRepository<T>> PersonService(R repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Iterable<T> getAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

}
```

For User entity:

```
public interface UserRepository extends PersonRepository<User> {

}
```

```
@Service
public class UserService extends PersonService<User> {

    public UserService(UserRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }

    public void additionalMethod() {
        User user = repository.getOne(1L);
    }
}
```

And I added Company entity by User entity example:

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends PersonRepository<Company> {

}
```

```
@Service
public class CompanyService extends PersonService<Company> {

    public CompanyService(CompanyRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }

    public void additionalMethod() {
        Optional<Company> company = repository.findById(1L);
    }
}
```